# How to convert from Generic List<double[]> to double[]?

Tags: c#, list, generics, collections, double

I have a Generic list that contains multiple double arrays.

```
List<double[]> d_list;
```

Suppose it contains many elements(i.e double arrays).
Now i want to:

1. get each element
2. convert that element from generic to double[]

How to do it?

Comment: Any reason why u have List of Array rather than list of list?

Comment: "Convert that element from generic to double[]" This makes no sense. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? In a generic `List<double[]>`, each element is *already* typed as a `double[]` and can be assigned to any variable of that type. No conversion is necessary; that is the whole idea behind generics.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to *flatten* the data; you can do it with a help of *Linq* : `SelectMany` to flatten, and `ToArray`, e.g.

```
 List<double[]> d_list = new List<double[]>() {
   new double[] {1, 2, 3},
   new double[] {}, // <- Empty array to be excluded from the final result
   new double[] {4},
   new double[] {5, 6}
 };

 // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
 double[] result = d_list
   .SelectMany(array => array) // Flatten
   .ToArray();                 // Materialized as an array
```

**Edit:** If you want 1st items from each array:

```
 // 1, 4, 5
 double[] result = d_list
   .Where(array => array.Any()) // non-empty arrays only
   .Select(array => array[0])   // 1st item from each array
   .ToArray();                  // Materialized as an array
```

Comment: it doesnt fetch me the first element which i want. instead it gives me all the elements in the list as one complete array.

Comment: @SayanSen Can you please provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: @Sayan Sen: if you want 1st item from each array - `{1, 4, 5}` in the sample, you can try a bit different Linq; see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesnt fetch me the first element which i want.

Try this:

```
    foreach (double[] element in d_list)
    {
         // ... do something with element ...
    }
```

or perhaps you wanted this:

```
    double[] element = d_list.FirstOrDefault();
```

Doesn't hurt to study C# a bit, [learn the fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/quick-starts/index).